# Updating an associative table in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Below is my (simplified) schema (in MySQL ver. 5.0.51b) and my strategy for updating it. There has got to be a better way. Inserting a new item requires 4 trips to the database and editing/updating an item takes up to **7**!

**items**: itemId, itemName

**categories**: catId, catName

**map**: mapId*, itemId, catId

* mapId (varchar) is concat of itemId + | + catId

1) If inserting: insert item. Get itemId via MySQL API.

Else updating: just update the item table. We already have the itemId.

2) Conditionally batch insert into `categories`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO categories (catName)
VALUES ('each'), ('category'), ('name');
```

3) Select IDs from `categories`.

```
SELECT catId FROM categories
WHERE catName = 'each' OR catName = 'category' OR catName = 'name';
```

4) Conditionally batch insert into `map`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO map (mapId, itemId, catId)
VALUES ('1|1', 1, 1), ('1|2', 1, 2), ('1|3', 1, 3);
```

If inserting: we're done. Else updating: continue.

5) It's possible that we no longer associate a category with this item that we did prior to the update. Delete old categories for this itemId.

```
DELETE FROM MAP WHERE itemId = 2
AND catID <> 2 AND catID <> 3 AND catID <> 5;
```

6) If we have disassociated ourselves from a category, it's possible that we left it orphaned. We do not want categories with no items. Therefore, if `affected rows > 0`, kill orphaned categories. I haven't found a way to combine these in MySQL, so this is #6 & #7.

```
SELECT categories.catId
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN map USING (catId)
GROUP BY categories.catId
HAVING COUNT(map.catId) < 1;
```

7) Delete IDs found in step 6.

```
DELETE FROM categories
WHERE catId = 9
  AND catId = 10;
```

Please tell me there's a better way that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Are `AUTO_INCREMENT` values involved?  Some solutions will "burn" them fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 6 & 7 can be combined easily enough:

```
DELETE categories.*
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN map USING (catId)
WHERE map.catID IS NULL;
```

Steps 3 & 4 can also be combined:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO map (mapId, itemId, catId)
    SELECT CONCAT('1|', c.catId), 1, c.catID
    FROM categories AS c
    WHERE c.catName IN('each','category','name');
```

Otherwise, your solution is pretty standard, unless you want to use triggers to maintain the map table.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do to make a bit easier:

- Read about [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`][1]
- Delete old categories before you insert new categories. This may benefit from an index better.

  `DELETE FROM map WHERE itemId=2`;
- You probably don't need `map.mapID`.  Instead, declare a compound primary key over `(itemID, catID)`.
- As Peter says in his answer, use MySQL's multi-table delete:

  ```
  DELETE categories.* FROM categories LEFT JOIN map USING (catId) 
  WHERE map.catID IS NULL
  ```

  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are worried about trips to the db, make steps into a stored procedure.  Then you have one trip.

Comment: Doh! You can tell someone was stuck in MySQL v3 land for far too long. Stored proc.s didn't even occur to me. Good call.

Comment: Funmy - I was trying to create a proc in 4 I think and it wasn't working.  I eventually realized it didn't have them.  I just couldn't believe it.  I think it was 4 anyway....